# How to do a one to many mapping by using Java lambdas and streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to split a list of numbers into multiples of 2, 3, 5 and store the result in a Map. Sample output will be like :

```
2 -> 2, 6, 10, 18 etc.
3 -> 3, 6, 9 etc.
5 -> 5, 10 etc.
```

I tried different ways of grouping (by using Collectors.groupingBy()) etc. in the collect() below and got compile errors each time. How do I do this ?

```
public void groupingByDemo() {
    //Split a list of numbers into multiples of 2, 3, 5. Store the result in a Map<Integer, Set>.
    List<Integer> multipliers = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5);
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 17, 25, 27);

    Map<Integer, Set> multiples = multipliers
            .stream().collect(
              //What to put here ? or should I use something else instead of collect() ?
            );
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what the output would look like?

Comment: 6 is a multiplier of both 2 and 3, so do you want 6 to appear as a value for both 2 and 3 keys in your map. Also please give some sample data and expected output when you post questions here. For more details please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @OleV.V. - I updated the question. Please re-open it.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala - I wonder if there is a faster way to get the question opened after making the edits. Ole V.V - Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: [How do I get a question reopened?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253277/how-do-i-get-a-question-reopened) And perhaps this one: [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) (rules have been changed after the latter question was asked, it now only takes three votes to reopen.)

Comment: I also voted to get the question reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
    List<Integer> multipliers = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5);
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 17, 25, 27);

    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = multipliers.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m,
                        m-> nums.stream()
                                .filter(n -> n % m == 0)
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
     map.forEach((m, n)-> System.out.println(m + " -> " + n));
```

Here is the output.

```
2 -> [16, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
3 -> [6, 9, 27]
5 -> [25, 10]
```

Comment: The type should be `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`. Also I don't think this will work because it seems you are grouping by `nums` instead of `multipliers`

Comment: You are correct about the typo and about the grouping.  I thought that is what the OP wanted.  A map of each number showing the divisors (2, 3, or 5) of that number.  That is why I asked for an example.  So the key of 10 would show a set of 2,5.  I guess my assumption was wrong.

Comment: @WJS - Sorry for the confusion. I have added sample output.

Comment: @tortytorty  That's okay.  I modified my answer for posterity.